# How to use Google Webfont loader only for specific paragraph classes?

Tags: css, webfonts, google-webfonts

I have been using the [Google Webfont loader](https://developers.google.com/webfonts/docs/webfont_loader) to display parts of my website with nice fonts. I have this part work fine, all of my `<p>` show with the font I want. However, I would like only some classes of `<p>` (i.e. `<p class="someclass">`) to show with the webfonts, and then the rest with regular font (i.e. not Google Webfonts). 
What is the best way for me to achieve this? At the moment, I am using this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      WebFontConfig = {
        google: { families: [ 'McLaren' ] }
      };
      (function() {
        var wf = document.createElement('script');
        wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
            '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
        wf.type = 'text/javascript';
        wf.async = 'true';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
      })();
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
      .wf-loading p.someclass {
        font-family: serif
      }
      .wf-inactive p.someclass {
        font-family: cursive
      }
      .wf-active p.someclass {
        font-family: 'McLaren', cursive
      }
    </style>
```

and all `<p>` throughout the page display with the 'McLaren' font. I'm sure I am doing something dumb with the CSS selector but I'm not quite sure what.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off you don’t necessarily need the js version of Google fonts I have just linked them through css and I have had no loading issues.  Secondly, someone would need to see your body of your actual html BUT you don’t need the p prefix just add the fonts to your class `.someclass{font-family:cursizve;}` also like I said using css pseudo classes work better and a lot lighter on the client

Comment: thanks, I just removed the p and it worked just fine. I wonder why I didn't try that in the first place...

Comment: yeah sorry for the late reply haven't been on, some browsers are weird and some css syntax is weird you just have to play around with it.